# pygame jump animation seems more like a rocket launch

Tags: python, pygame

using this code everything seems right to me. First the player should go up, then once `jumpcount` turns negative, it should go down, but the movement seems more like a rocket that is never going to land. Could someone tell me what’s wrong with my code?

```py
def movement():
    jump = False
    jumpcount = 10
    keyspressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keyspressed[pygame.K_w]:
        jump = True
    if jump == True:
        if jumpcount>=-10:
            player.y -= (jumpcount * abs(jumpcount))*0.5
            jumpcount-=1
        else:
            jump = False
            jumpcount = 10
```

Comment: `jump` and `jumpcount ` are local variables. The value of `jumpcount` is always 10.

Comment: Yes, everything fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jump` and `jumpcount` need to be variables in global namespace. These variables need to keep their value beyond frames. Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) if you want to change variables  in global namespace within a function (see [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)):

```py
jump = False
jumpcount = 10

def movement():
    global jump, jumpcount
   
    keyspressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if not jump and keyspressed[pygame.K_w]:
        jump = True
        jumpcount = 10
    
    if jump == True:
        if jumpcount>=-10:
            player.y -= (jumpcount * abs(jumpcount))*0.5
            jumpcount-=1
        else:
            jump = False
            jumpcount = 10
```

See alos [How to make a character jump in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873880/how-to-make-a-character-jump-in-pygame/65874132#65874132)